# Is there a open in browser right click option in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I know there's Run and then you can select your preferred browser but I'd like something like: right click on file -> open in Google Chrome.

Is there a plugin which does this desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the *contextMenu.xml* file:

- Go to *Settings->Edit Popup ContextMenu*
- Click OK on popup that say that you must restart Notepad for apply changes
- Add *Item* tag code that you need to the file:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <NotepadPlus>
      <ScintillaContextMenu>
          ...
          <!-- Put this in the position you like most -->
          <Item MenuEntryName="Run" MenuItemName="Launch in Chrome"/>
          <Item MenuEntryName="Run" MenuItemName="Launch in IE"/>
          <!-- Put this if you want to insert a line between fields -->
          <Item id="0"/>
          ...
      </ScintillaContextMenu>
  </NotepadPlus>
  ```
- Restart Notepad++
- Right click on the open file and you should see:

[image]

Hope this help you.